# Meteor - Conditionally return a group of event Handlers

Tags: meteor

In Meteor what is the best way to conditionally add a set of event handlers?

For example I'm trying to do something like this code below (this code does not work, but you will get the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.)

```
Template.page_article.events( function(){
  if (something){
    return {
      some_event_name1,
      some_event_name2,
    }
  } else {
    return {
      some_event_name3,
      some_event_name4,
    }
  }
})
```

What is the best way to do this? I tried to set a variable outside the events() but I do not like that solution because the variable gets shared amongst ALL other templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve sounds like a bad solution to me, but here's a way to do it:

```js
Template.page_article.events((function(){
  if (something){
    return {
      '<event>': function(){ console.log("A1") },
      '<event>': function(){ console.log("A2") }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      '<event>': function(){ console.log("B1") },
      '<event>': function(){ console.log("B2") }
    }
  }
})())
```

**EDIT**

And with your added comment, it definitely sounds like a bad solution. Do something like this instead:

```js
Template.page_article.events({
    '<event>': function(event, template){
        if(something){
            console.log("Do something A1")
        }else{
            console.log("Do something B1")
        }
    }
    '<event>': function(event, template){
        if(something){
            console.log("Do something A2")
        }else{
            console.log("Do something B2")
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks but can you help me get Template data where the variable SOMETHING is? I tried Template.currentData() but no avail. I'm trying to check if an "edit_mode" variable is true or false. If true, all the events that allow editing is returned, if not then the events aren't returned.

Comment: Well, Your second editted solution IS what I have been doing. Except there are like 20 events that I do NOT want to be run at all if something is false. It made more sense to me to not run all of it period instead if possible instead of doing the same if check 20 times. But I guess for now this will have to do.